# How do I check if a certain User exists under a specific Login in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, authentication

I'm using the following code to create a user:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'PROD\Secure_user')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [PROD\Secure_user] FOR LOGIN [PROD\Secure_user]
END
```

But I don't think my error check is sufficient. What if I had ran the following code previously:

```
CREATE USER [PROD\Secure_user] FOR LOGIN [PROD\Something_else]
```

My IF statement above would still be false, right? Because it is not checking which Login the user exists for, just that there is one that exists with that name. So my question is, how do I check that a login exits for a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = 'PROD\Secure_user'
           AND loginname = 'PROD\Secure_user')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [PROD\Secure_user] FOR LOGIN [PROD\Secure_user]
END
```

If the user is a windows user (`select name, type_desc from sys.database_principals`), I think it is a requirement that the loginname and name from syslogins match. But someone more knowledgeable should confirm. Possible source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx

---

In response to the feedback below, this joins on `sid`.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
SET @name = 'PROD\Secure_user'

IF (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM master.dbo.syslogins sl
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON sl.sid=dp.sid AND sl.name=dp.name
    WHERE sl.name=@name AND sl.loginname = @name
    ) > 0
BEGIN
    CREATE USER @name FOR LOGIN @name
END
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the database user already exists, but is linked to a different sql server login.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think the SIDs need to match for that to ever happen. Could a join on sid confirm? I am assuming this is a windows user which could be wrong. Can you verify my edit? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I just tested in SQL 2008 R2.  A db user of any name can be linked to a SQL Server login created from Windows.  When I query `sys.database_principals` on the user, `type_desc` shows 'WINDOWS_USER'.  Probably not what most people would expect...

Comment: do the `sid`s still match? Should I scrap my answer, or is it workable into an alternative solution? Edited my answer with a possible way of checking what I said.

Comment: @DMason This seems like it would check if a valid user is created, but not if an invalid one exists. Could we just drop that user if they exist, but that condition is not met?

Comment: Yes, the `sid`s still match.  I think the sid for a Windows Authentication sql server login correlates to the unique identifier of the Active Directory login (which I think is also called a `sid`).  As for the db user sid, [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328(v=sql.105).aspx) is a little vague IMO.

Comment: The revision still doesn't work if the database user already exists, but is linked to a different sql server login.  At some point, an `ALTER USER` statement would have to be performed.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DMason. I think I understand your point. I am hesitant to edit anymore, since it got accepted, but the OP should read your comments. I'll upvote your answer too so it can be seen as well.

Comment: The first option Gray mentioned here worked for me. I read through the comments, but for my case I don't need to worry about the same user being linked to other logins. But it is definitely useful information. Thanks!

Comment: @intA: "I don't need to worry about the same user being linked to other logins."  Ok, now I'm confused.  I thought that was the point of your question in the first place.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DMason No, actually you're totally right. I think I need to get a better understanding of users vs logins in the first place. I just didn't want to make this too complicated. I'm trying to add this code in to a procedure and make it re-runable so if it gets run a second time it won't error out and say "User x already exists" and stop the procedure. But I want to make sure it is looking at the correct use and not saying "User X already exists" when the user X it is talking about is actually under a different login.

Answer (score 2):

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO

--First, verify the "right" sql server login exists.
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM master.sys.syslogins WHERE name = 'PROD\Secure_user' )
BEGIN
    --This is your original query.  Continue to use it, since it creates the
    --database user if it does not exist.
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'PROD\Secure_user')
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER [PROD\Secure_user] FOR LOGIN [PROD\Secure_user]
    END

    --You know the database user exists, because of the above statement.
    --However, if the above statement didn't create the database user,
    --it may be linked to the "wrong" sql server login.  This statement
    --will correct that in either circumstance.
    ALTER USER [PROD\Secure_user] 
    WITH LOGIN = [PROD\Secure_user]
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR('SQL Server login [PROD\Secure_user] does not exist.', 16, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add any timestamp column to the table and check the latest one.
or else check the count of users,based on the do the validation.

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT count(1) FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'PROD\Secure_user')>1)
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER [PROD\Secure_user] FOR LOGIN [PROD\Secure_user]
    END
```